# OSGi Servlet with HSQLDB

Tags: servlets, osgi, hsqldb

I am looking for an easy way to use HSQLDB with an OSGi Servlet. I allready created an OSGi Bundle out of the HSQLDB.jar following this guide:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html

But now I can't seem to figure out how to use the HSQLDB from a Servlet inside another Bundle. I can't find any good step by step guides either. I would appreciate if someone could point me into the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSQLDB has an 'official' bundle in the [MvnRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb/2.2.8). Generally it pays off to look around for bundles before converting one yourself. Sometimes it's easy, but often it's trickier to get right. 
Mind you, the article you quote is quite old and (while still correct as far as I can see), there are many more possibilities nowadays.

In any case, to work in OSGi, you need to understand how services work. From that point on, servlets are services, and no different than any other service.

When I started fooling around with OSGi, the [Felix documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html) was a great help to me. I also recommend taking a look at Declarative Services.